# Nest thermostat wiring problems

Tags: electrical, thermostat

Removing my old Honeywell thermostat to replace with the nest. I live in Florida and my ac unit is 10 years old. I’m not sure if I have conventional heat or a pump. I took a picture of the old one but I cannot upload it.

- Blue went to C
- Green went to G
- Yellow went to Y
- Orange went to O/B or W
- Red went to R with a silver little splitter thing to RC
- White went to W2/AUX.

After following the nest instructions I could not get the unit to power on.

Comment: Post the photo to [imgur](https://imgur.com) and post a link here, then we can get it uploaded for you.  Also, can you post photos of the wiring at your air-handler/furnace?

Comment: You won't be able to hook this up if you don't know basics like furnace or heat pump.  It may be tiem to call a Nest installer.

Comment: Red wire should go to Rc on the Nest if it has one (or just R), but the nest will need to be programmed to work with a conventional or heat pump.  If you don't know, that's a problem.  It's _probably_ a heat pump based on the old wiring, but you need to know for sure.